# How to position a Div on right hand side with html

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble positioning a div to the right side of the screen. here is my code snippet.
for html

```
<div id="bannerR">
<a href="google.comtarget=_blank>
<img src="google.com" border=0></a>
</div>
```

and here is what i have for .css

```
#bannerR { position: relative; right; }
```

please help. thank you

Comment: #bannerL{ 
position: relative;
float: right;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
    #bannerL
    { 
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    }
```

add float: right;

Answer (score 0):

float: right; in the css should do the trick

```
#bannerL { position: relative; float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#bannerL{ position: relative;top:0; right:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div id="bannerL">
<center>
<a href="http:google.com">
<img src="google.com" 

width="468" height="60">
</a></center>
</div>
```

css:

```
#bannerL{ position: relative; right:0; top:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dd63m/14/  for Live Demo

```
<style>
#bannerL{ position: relative; 
    float:right; }
</style>

<div id="bannerL">

<a href="http:google.com">
<img src="google.com" 

width="468" height="60">
</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

So here is the working code:

HTML:

```
<div id="bannerL">
<center>
<a href="http:google.com">
<img src="google.com" width="468" height="60">
</a></center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bannerL{ position: relative; float:right; }
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M2smA/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid CSS property like this : `position: relative; right;`.

If you want to move Element to right side. You can use CSS [`float`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) property.

**CSS:**

```
#bannerL { 
   position: relative; 
   float: right; 
}
```

[Try in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2smA/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container{
                border: 1px solid blue;
                text-align: right;
            }
            .logo{
                border: 1px solid red;
                background-color: gray;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                LOOOGO
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```